# What will happen if the pthreadId is zero in pthread_join(pthreadId, NULL) on Android?

Tags: android-ndk, pthreads, pthread-join

What will happen if the pthreadId is zero in **pthread_join(pthreadId, NULL)** 
 on Android ? Like the following code snippet:

```
pthread_join(0, NNULL);
```

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it? Also, what would 0 signify here according to you? Any thread..?

Comment: @Michael Maybe the question is ambiguous. In fact, I need to know if there is potential risk. I will edit the question to more clearly.

Comment: It depends on what you think joining thread zero is supposed to mean. The `pthread_join` documentation states that _"There is no pthreads analog of ... "join with any terminated thread".  If you believe you need this functionality, you probably need to rethink your application design"_. Another thing stated in the documentation is that attempting to join a previously joined thread results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your explanation. Is  "pthread is 0"  valid on Android?

Answer (score 1):

pthread_join() is used to **wait** for termination of the thread specified by **thread id**. This is needed so that process should not exit before thread finishes its execution.

The thread is identified by thread id. Now if you give 0 as thread id, it will not find the thread and return an error immediately.

So, if you are using 0 as thread id for all the threads created, it's possible that before the threads finish the assigned work, the process may exit.

In my system, if I give 0 as thread id, it returned error number 3(ESRCH  No thread with the ID thread could be found.)

Few points:

- You can print the thread id and check what values are normally given
  for thread id to understand it better.
- You might need the abstract type of the thread id to print its
  value. Please search in /usr/include/.../pthreadtypes.h to get abstract type of pthread_t. In my system its **unsigned long int**.

  ```
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h:typedef unsigned long int         pthread_t;
  ```
- While debugging with GDB, it assigns thread number to each thread. Next to Thread is thread id assigned by pthread_create. For thread number 1, thread id is 0x7f5750718740.

  ```
  (gdb) info threads
    Id   Target Id         Frame 
  * 1    Thread 0x7f5750718740 (LWP 9215) "a.out" 0x00007f57502f2d2d in         __GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex (
      threadid=140012979980032, thread_return=0x0, abstime=0x0, block=<optimized         out>) at pthread_join_common.c:89
    2    Thread 0x7f574fef8700 (LWP 9216) "a.out" __lll_lock_wait ()
      at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
  ```

Please check [Tech Easy](http://techeasyblogs.blogspot.com/)  for more information on threads.